# jquery $.get() doesn't return a string but an object

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm working on an app that gets an xml file, wraps it to a json object and runs it trough a handlebars templates.

I'm using the jquery $.get() function to get the data from an xml file. However, i get an object (Document) returned, and i need the contents of my xml file as a string.

```
$.get(appCore.location, function (data){return data //but it's an object}
```

If you need more code, give a shout, but i'm not doing anything more than a simple $.get().

thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Content-type header of the response to text-plain.

Comment: This answer is correct, i had to set the dataType to "text" instead of "xml". $.get(appCore.location, doThisFuntion, "text")

Answer (score 1):

You don't always get a string from $.get(), read [here:](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

> returned data, which will be an XML root element, text string, JavaScript file, or JSON object, depending on the MIME type of the response.

You are probably getting a JSON object, so just run it through stringify:

```
var result = JSON.stringify(data);
```